# virt-manager connect to kvm w/o password

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I want to connect my KVM host with virt-manager, but I use pub key for authentication, and I cant skip the openssh-password popup.

Is it possible to log in without a password?

(i apologize for my bad english)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

> virt-manager -c qemu+ssh://username@host1.example.org/system